# Tab does not work with vim for me

Tags: vimrc, gvim

Problem statement :-
Tab does not work with vim for me

Description :-
I am using vim-awesome for plugin in vim. Now the tab does not work. My expectation is pressing should result in tab being inserted in my file

Comment: Need more details. You mean `Tab` was working before you installed the plugin and now it isn't? Are you in insert mode when pressing `Tab`?

Comment: Does it insert spaces instead? If yes, see `:h 'expandtab'`.

Comment: @algae, yes it was working. And yes i am insert mode. Also insert mode, if CTRL-V and TAB it works

Comment: @raif , i did not understand, it shows the manual how the behaviour is

Comment: @VenumadhavJosyula Welcome to [vi.se]! I’ve temporarily closed your question because it lacks significant details. If you can [edit] to clarify, we can reopen the question. (You might want to describe what « not working » means and which plugin you installed that started this behavior. We have a good question on debugging mappings too.) I also recommend the [tour] and [help] if you’re new!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds, as if the option `expandtab` is set. In this case Vim inserts spaces instead of a tab character.

To check execute `set expandtab?`. This will either print `expandtab` ( Vim inserts spaces) or `noexpandtab` (Vim will insert real tabs).

To get real tabs, you need to execute `:set noexpandtab` or add it to your `vimrc`.

---

So the question remains: Why is `expandtab` set?

To find the "guilty" part, restart Vim and execute `:verbose set expandtab?`. This will echo the current state and print where is was last set.